# Android ARCore use TextureView in a ViewRenderable

Tags: android, arcore

So I have a custom view that uses a TextureView in order to render it's content through OpenGL and JNI, which works as intented.

Now, looking at the ARCore demos (and documentation) it is posible to render Android Views using the 
[ViewRenderable](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/sceneform/rendering/ViewRenderable) class. But doing a quick test using my custom view, it appears that it won't work, since it wasn't made thinking in this kind of behavior...

So I have two questions here:

1. It is possible to use a TextureView as a custom renderable in ARCore?
2. If not, is there a way to have a delimited area (anchored in a given point) where I can freely make my JNI/OpenGL calls?

If someone could point me out where in the documentation (or demos) can I look out will be highly appreciated